# Determining last stop of underground line

Tags: prolog

Modelling the stops of an underground tube line like so:

```
stop(line1, 1, a).
stop(line1, 2, b).
stop(line1, 3, d).
stop(line1, 4, e).
```

I'm trying to define `last(L, S)` that is true if the station `S` is the last station in the line `L`. So `last(line1, e)` is true, but `last(line1, d)` isn't.

I've tried `last(L, S) :- stop(L, N, S), \+stop(L, N+1, _).` but it returns true for every stop on the line, and I don't see why. A station is the last stop of a line if it a) exists on that line, and b) if the line has no stop after it. Correct?

I guess it's something to do with the negation part - I'm still wrapping my head around negation in Prolog...

Comment: It's because Prolog does not evaluate expressions, so your `N+1` is not having the effect you think it has. `last(L,S) :- stop(L, N, S), N1 is N+1, \+ stop(L, N1, _).`

Comment: Thank you. Could you clarify on what's meant by not evaluating expressions? What exactly is going on with my faulty code?

Comment: Sure. Go to your terminal and type `X = 1 + 2.` You'll see that Prolog does not reduce arithmetic expressions unless asked to with `is/2`. In other languages, if you call (say) `foo(X+1)`, the language evaluates X+1, reducing it to (say) 4 and then calls `foo(4)`. In Prolog, that does not happen. This turns out to be useful for writing evaluators, but it is a stumbling block for new users like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake in Prolog is that Prolog does *not* attach semantics to the `+`, `-`, etc.

If you write:

```
?- X = 3 + 1.
X = 3+1.
```

it does not *interpret* this as a mathematical expression where it calculates the result, it simply sees it as a functor with two arguments.

Of course Prolog *can* interpret this term as a mathematical expression, and if the variables are properly instantiated, calculate the result. One uses the [**`is/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) for that:

```
?= X is 3 + 1.
X = 4.
```

So we here can evaluate `N+1` and store it in a variable:

```
last(L, S) :-
    stop(L, N, S),
    N1 is N+1,
    \+stop(L, N1, _).
```